# JavaScript Promises - Creating an array of promises to be executed together

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

I'm working with Node.js on async calls to noSQL DynamoDB.  I first query to see which 'buddy list(s)' the account belongs.  That may return from zero to 'n' new Primary Keys that will contain lists of all of the members of each of those buddy lists.  Think of them as clubs to which a person belongs... you may have none or many; each club has several members or even one.

So far (and I am working with Promises for the first time here... though I have used callbacks on prior JA projects) I'm OK with where I am, but I know that I am assembling the array of promises incorrectly.  That is, I can see in the console that the .then function executes before both promises resolve.  For the record, I do expect that... it seems reasonable that any .then may be satisfied with a single promise resolving.

Anyways, Can someone offer up some tips as to how to structure?  I'd like to end up with pseudo:

getBuddyLists
.then(getAllTheBuddiesInTheLists)
.then(function(){//doSomething});

my Node.js code:

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
const docClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient({region:'us-east-1'});
var buddyGroups = [];

exports.handler = function(event, context, callback) {
    var params = {
        TableName: 'USER_INFORMATION',
        Key: {
            "DEVICE_ID": event.DEVICE_ID
        }
    };

    var getBuddyList = new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
        docClient.get(params, function(err, data){
            if(err){
                reject(err);
            }
            else{
                var dataJSON = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data));
                dataJSON.Item.my_buddies.values.forEach(function(value){
                    buddyGroups.push(value);
                });
                console.log('Got buddy groups: ' + buddyGroups);
                resolve(buddyGroups);
            }
        });
    });

    getBuddyList.then(function(capturedData){  // capturedData => an array of primary keys in another noSQL document
        console.log('groups: ' + capturedData);
        var myPromises = [];
        capturedData.forEach(function(value){
            var reqParams = {
                        TableName: "buddy_list",
                        Key: {"BUDDY_ID": value}
                    };
            myPromises.push(new Promise (function(resolve, reject){
                docClient.get(reqParams, function(err, data){
                    if(err){
                        //console.log(err, data);
                    reject(err);
                    }else{
                        var returnedJSON = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data));
                        console.log(returnedJSON);
                        resolve(returnedJSON);
                    }
                });
            }));
        });
        //
        Promise.all(myPromises); // ADDED IN EDIT <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
        // how to make sure all of myPromises are resolved?
        //
    }).then(function(){
            console.log("done");
        })
    .catch(function(err){
        console.log("error message:" + error);
    });
};
```

EDIT: Added location of Promise.all(myPromises);

Comment: unrelated, but you should use `myPromises = capturedData.map(...)` instead of a `.forEach` / `.push` loop

Comment: @Alnitak,coming from C++ it's hard for me to shed the for-loop paradigm!  I suppose you offer that up due to the blocking nature of .forEach... or some other reason?

Comment: .forEach has no "blocking nature" ... the `.map` pattern is just more efficient ... `Promise.all(capturedData.map(function(value) { ... return(new Promise ...` - no need for the `myPromises` var at all

Comment: @JimfromPrinceton no, it's simpler than that - if you've got an array as input, and want an equal sized array as output (with a 1:1 mapping between input elements and output elements) then `.map` is simply the right function for the job.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Just to clarify how you would use `Promise.all`, even though you accepted an answer, you edited the question, but still are not using it correctly

Also, the discussion of .map vs .forEach - this is how you would use .map

```
    getBuddyList.then(function(capturedData){  // capturedData => an array of primary keys in another noSQL document
        console.log('groups: ' + capturedData);
        // changes to use .map rather than .forEach
        // also, you need to RETURN a promise - your edited code did not
        return Promise.all(capturedData.map(function(value){
            return new Promise (function(resolve, reject){
                var reqParams = {
                    TableName: "buddy_list",
                    Key: {"BUDDY_ID": value}
                };
                docClient.get(reqParams, function(err, data){
                    if(err){
                        //console.log(err, data);
                    reject(err);
                    }else{
                        var returnedJSON = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data));
                        console.log(returnedJSON);
                        resolve(returnedJSON);
                    }
                });
            });
        }));
    }).then(function(){
            console.log("done");
        })
    .catch(function(err){
        console.log("error message:" + error);
    });
```

Comment: Thanks for posting the proper code...  I appreciate that (along with the use of .map()

Answer (score 2):

You're looking for `Promise.all(myPromises)`, which returns a single promise of an array of the results of the promises.

Comment: So, must all of the promises contained in the .then-able context required to resolve before .then happens?

Comment: @JimfromPrinceton exactly! https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all

Comment: @AlvMF1 ,  I added as per the edit above but my log suggest that my .then happens before all the promises are resolved:

START RequestId:  Version: $LATEST
2017-01-17T23:23:19  Got buddy groups: 12345,ABCDE
2017-01-17T23:23:19  groups: 12345,ABCDE
2017-01-17T23:23:19  done here
2017-01-17T23:23:19        { Item: 
   { BUDDY_ID: '12345',
     member: { values: [Object], type: 'String' } } }
2017-01-17T23:23:19  { Item: 
   { BUDDY_ID: 'ABCDE',
     member: { values: [Object], type: 'String' } } }
END

Comment: `return Promise.all(myPromises);`